# EXCEL File not downloading contain #(hash) symbol in name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using excel library to create & download excel file.

```
$name="ABC #TEST";
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->excel->stream($name.'.xls', $data);
```

When I remove # from name it downloads the excel file. Otherwise it redirects me to error page.

Please help and thanks.

Comment: why do you need to put a #(hash) on your file name? please specify what answer you are looking.

Comment: [urlencode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it maybe?

Comment: its just a name , @SessionStart

Comment: I used urlencode() this before and its adds + symbol before # (hash) @kerbholz

Comment: And it should also replace your `#` with `%23`

Comment: it did not replace # to %12 .. @kerbholz

Comment: I want to download excel file which contain #symbol in its name @SessionStart

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download it with **#(hash)** try this one out.

```
$filename='ABC #TEST.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
//save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
//if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
//force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

hope that helps.